# Translating large JSON dataset from REST API to a New Transformed File

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writing a JavaScript function that pulls a (largish) JSON dataset from a REST API. The purpose of the function is to then pick through the various pieces of the JSON that are needed because there is a ton of stuff that I don't really need. Then, I put that information in a new, transformed file. I have been searching for some best practices on how to handle this.

Should I simply create an array of objects that represents the transformed output file I am creating and then take the pieces I need from each JSON object and put that in this new object?

Also, should I parse all the JSON data first and bundle it into an array of objects? And then take the array and objects and generate my new output, transformed file? Or is there some other way to stream the REST API in and go straight to a new output file?

Just looking for thoughts and best practices on going about this? Didn't know about blocking and memory issues with needing to house all this data.

The only articles I have found online is just simple parsing of JSON via JSON.parse and then picking a couple of pieces. But my JSON is tons of various objects

Answer (score 1):

A large part of this depends on how the API is set up. If it's a more modern rest API then it might be set up to be routed so you can request the specific path to a resource. For instance if the url was `...path/to/data.json`, getting to the first record could be done through a network call to `...path/to/data.json[0]`. This would allow you to retrieve just one record at a time instead of blocking everything.

Unfortunately there's not much of an alternative if it's not set up that way. You'd have to try to download the entire table as a JSON and then parse it from there. If you have any familiarity with Node.js you could still do something with JavaScript to parse the file. At that point it would just be a matter of doing `Array.filter` or `Array.map` and creating a new JSON file based on what you needed.

Comment: Thanks... so I am using the Vimeo REST API, and I am using it to pull all the videos for a particular user and there is tons of meta data that I just don't need. I specifically just need the name of the video, description, and URL to the video. I haven't seen anything in the docs about routing. I will check into the Array.map...